# How to send email directly from Android device in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am curious about sending emails from an Android device directly. I tried to do so using sendgrid, but I got a conflict in the HTTP library. I also tried to achieve that using Intent, but with Action SEND.TO I can't detect if user actually sent the email or not (always returns false). Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank should be expressed only after you were helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to send emails with MailGun. Mailgun is an email service provider for developers. It gives transactional email API Service, so you don't need to worry about creating your own SMTP server. Mailgun gives us a RESTful API to perform email operations. I would recommend this article for further study and implementation.
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/mailgun-android-example/

Answer (score 1):

> "I tried to do so using sendgrid, but I got a conflict in the HTTP
> library."

Sendgrid's Java library is not tuned to work with Android out-of-the-box unfortunately and encounters issues like you've discovered.

I have created and continue to maintain an Android Sendgrid library that you are welcome to use.

https://github.com/jakebreen/android-sendgrid

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.3.1'
}
```

Raise an issue on the repository's issue board if you any queries.